Left Hilbert algebra: tracial case (Stratila-Zsido: Exercise 10.5)
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a left Hilbert algebra. In the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila and Zsido, there is the following exercise:

E.10.5: Show that the following statements are equivalent:
$(1)$ $\Delta=1$
$(2)$ $S$ is isometric
$(3)$ $\varphi_{\mathcal{A}}$ is a trace.

I refer to this book for the definitions of this standard notation.
I am having trouble proving the implication $(2)\implies (3)$. The other implications are no problem. More specifically, my proof is complete once I can show that for $x\in \mathcal{L}(A)$, we have that
$$\varphi_{\mathcal{A}}(x^*x) < \infty \implies \varphi_{\mathcal{A}}(xx^*) < \infty$$
(by symmetry, this shows the traciality condition on elements of infinite weight).
Equivalently, if $|x|= L_\xi$ for some $\xi \in \mathcal{A}''$, I want to show that $|x^*|= L_\eta$ for appropriate $\eta \in \mathcal{A}''$. I played around with polar decomposition arguments for $x$ but didn't get far. Any ideas?

What you want is done on page 282. $\def\cA{\mathcal A}$
You have that $\varphi_{\cA}(x^*x)<\infty$. This means that $|x|=L_{\xi_0}$ for some $\xi\in\cA''$. If $x=v|x|$ is the polar decomposition, then $$x=v|x|=vL_{\xi_0}.  $$
Now, for any $\eta\in\cA'$,
$$
R_\eta(v\xi_0)=vR_\eta\xi_0=vL_{\xi_0}\eta=x\eta, 
$$
and
$$
R_\eta(S\xi_0 v^*)=R_{v^*\eta}(S\xi_0)=(L_{\xi_0})^*v^*\eta=x^*\eta.
$$
Then Proposition 10.4 implies that $$\xi=v\xi_0\in\cA'',\qquad S\xi=S\xi_0v^*,\qquad L_\xi=x. $$
Knowing that $x=L_\xi$, one gets
$$
|x|=L_{v^*\xi},\qquad\qquad |x^*|=L_{vS\xi}. 
$$
Therefore, since $S$ is an isometry,
$$
\varphi_\cA(xx^*)=\varphi_\cA(|x^*|^2)=\|vS\xi\|^2=\|S\xi\|^2=\|\xi\|^2=\varphi_\cA(x^*x). 
$$

Thanks for your answer. Hm I seem to have another version of the book. But if you are referring to what I think, then this is not quite the same. There the author starts from $x=L_\xi$ and not from the absolute value.

I didn't know there was more than one version, I'm using the original. I added a few more details, check it out.

Thanks. I see some typos now, but you seem to be implicitly using that $v^*\eta \in \mathcal{A}'$ (to make the commutation between the L and R operator). Why is this the case?

I might be missing something, but I wasn't assuming that $v^\eta\in\cA'$. I was doing $$ (L_{\xi_0})^\eta=R_\eta(\xi_0^{#})=R_\eta(S\xi_0), $$ regardless of $\eta$ being in the commutant or not.

Thanks for the reply. As far as I am aware, the operator $R_\eta$ is only defined as a bounded operator for $\eta \in \mathcal{A}'$. I don't understand in your answer how $R_{v^*\eta}$ makes sense.

I'm not very familiar with this chapter, so I cannot say for sure if I'm not mixing things. But on Lemma 10.2.2 it says that $R_\eta$ is defined for all $\eta$ in the domain of $S^$. And here $S$ is an isometry, so the domain of $S^$ is everything.

Thanks. Still not entirely clear to me. Before I continue, can you maybe fix the typo $S\xi_0 v^*$ in your answer? Maybe I am just misunderstanding something you meant to write.

I'm sorry, I had a couple of ideas on how to repair that, but I couldn't  make them work in the little time I had available. I'll try again when I have some time.

Thanks for the help anyway!
